# Performance issue for session with TPT write

Tags: teradata, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have session which taking data from AS400 and loading into Teradata. Source having 182 columns and ~19 millions records. I am using TPT write connection for writing data on Teradata. Target table is truncate and load and mapping is straight mapping. Still I am getting 6 throughput (Row/sec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it down: is it a source/transformation/target bottleneck?
Modify the mapping and add a filter (criterion: FALSE) straight after the source and see how fast it runs, do the same right before target (if you have a little bit more than ‘straight’)

Then get back to us :)

More concrete: 182 columns is a bit much... perhaps you need to increase the buffer block size to allow for at least 100 rows per block